# Issue using custom HttpModule with ajax enabled (ScriptManager) asp.net webform (ASP.NET 4.0 / IIS 7 )

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0, httpmodule, scriptmanager

I've a custom Httpmodule which handles PostAuthenticateRequest & PreRequestHandlerExecute events.

However, when I try to use the module on page with ReportViwer (which needs ScriptManager) I get a bunch of browser errors such as following and the report viewer does not work as expected i.e. it doesn't show any result.

1. ASP.NET Ajax client-side framewook failed to load.
2. 'Sys' is undefined
3. Syntax error (WebResource.axd)
4. 'Type' is undefined (ReportViewerWebControl.axd)

If I comment out the module from web.config everything works as expected (obviously without the module code). Can anyone help me understand and resolve this issue?

Thanks!!

Comment: What does your module do?  It sounds like what ever code you have in your module, is interfering with the default processing of those pages.

Comment: Tony ... the module uses database to determine user roles (R) for the current application and updates the current principal with it (R). It then uses the grants defined for the current page in database to determine users access to it. It also adds these roles to user session object. I'm not sure how that corresponds to interference with default processing because my code is completely custom. However, what is default processing of ajax enabled web page?

Answer (score 2):

I might have found a workaround to make my code work. However, I'm at loss to explain the default processing of ajax enabled web page.

I would like to thank Tony for his insight, which got me thinking in this direction.

To test the processing, I ran the module with the ajax enabled page which had an update panel which printed current system time. The update panel refreshed based on a timer control which went off every 10 seconds. What I observed was that for every request multiple calls were made to the httpmodule. The first call to the module has header that contained about 7 key-value pair such as Connection, Authorization, Host etc. The subsequent calls had some extra key-value pair among which couple of them caught my attention. They are x-requested-with and x-microsoftajax, which I believe XHttpRequest ... an ajax request.

So, in my workaround I just skipped processing of my module depending on presence of these header value somthing like the following.

```
 if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["x-microsoftajax"] == null)
 { ... old code ... }
```

Once I do that, the module gets executed the during the first call and the execution is skipped every time its called as part of ajax processing.